# jQuery animations performance with Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari, jqtouch

I've just recently started developing a site for iPhone using jQTouch, and have the following code:

```
<li class="title" onclick="showDesc('desc1');">Post Title</li>
   <li id="desc1" class="shortDesc">
      Short description of post content
      <a href="#viewPost">Read</a> 
   </li>

<script type="text/css>
function showDesc(id){
    $("#"+id).slideToggle();
}
</script>
```

"desc1" is hidden in the CSS and displayed when the user clicks the post title (I'm just working on a mockup, so the argument passed to showDesc() is hardcoded at the moment)

My problem is that when viewing it on the iPhone itself, the animation is incredibly slow and stuttery. It runs fine in desktop browsers (obviously!) and the iPhone simulator, it's just on the unit itself (running iOS 4.3.2).

My question is this: Is this an issue with my code or is it a case of jQuery not having been optimized for Mobile Safari?

I'm using jQTouch for the mobile framework, but the documentation only discusses page transitions by way of animation, so I'm not sure if there's a way of doing it with that.

Alternatively, would this task be better suited to CSS3 animation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is highly recomended to use CSS3 transitions. They are hardware accelerated, whereas Javascript animations are not. You would want to transition opacity as well as width/height parameters for the slideToggle animation. It's nasty, but it gives you great performance

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS3 animations on mobile as "CSS rendering engine" has more opportunities to optimize performance. Especially things like transitioning transforms (things that do not cause re-layouts and re-rendering of textures) - they are mapped on hardware pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that a lot of the rendering issues on the phone itself were caused by the webkit-box-shadow property applied to the hidden <li>

Although CSS3 is a much more "native" option for this task, the jQuery slideToggle() function seems to work perfectly well.

I really ought to have given a more detailed overview of the CSS, but have now learned more about CSS3 animation based on your recommendation, so it was worth it!